# Change DataTemplate in codebehind file dynamcailly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the DataTemplate below, which decides what .png to show based on the DirType. Currently, if we get DirType of 3, we show ./images/file.png

```
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DirType}" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Image.Source" TargetName="img" Value="./Images/MyComputer.jpg"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DirType}" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Image.Source" TargetName="img" Value="./Images/diskdrive.png"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DirType}" Value="2">
                <Setter Property="Image.Source" TargetName="img" Value="./Images/folder.png"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Text" TargetName="ObjType" Value="File Folder"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DirType}" Value="3">
                <Setter Property="Image.Source" TargetName="img" Value="./Images/file.png"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Text" TargetName="ObjType" Value="{Binding Ext}"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ObjSize" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Text" TargetName="ObjSize" Value="{Binding Size}"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},Path=IsSelected}" Value="True" >

            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Then I use it in a ListBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="dirList" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"

             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DirViewTemplate}" BorderThickness="0" 
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" 
             Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" 
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
             SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentItem,Mode=OneWayToSource}"
             MouseDoubleClick="dirList_MouseDoubleClick"
             KeyDown="dirList_KeyDown">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ItemWidth="220"></WrapPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
```

Now, I want to dynamically change the image displayed for file type value = 3 based on their file types. Before all files have the same icon displayed in the list box but now I want them to pull the icons displayed in Windows explorer. I tried to access the DataTemplate dynamically while adding the items to the list, but I couldnt get it to work.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Use a **MultiDataTrigger**. This defines a number of conditions, all of which much evaluate to true for the trigger's setters to be applied.

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=DirType}" Value="3" />
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Ext}" Value="txt" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Source" Value="./Images/txt-file.png" />
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

Here you have two conditions, one bound to the `DirType` property value, the other bound to the `Ext` property value. If `DirType` is "3" and `Ext` is "txt", then the setter will be applied (ie. the image source will change to use a different image file).

Just repeat the trigger in the XAML, changing the binding values, to deal with other file types.